# Javascript NaN when summing Num

Tags: javascript, html, nan, forms

I'm making a simple webapp that takes 2 values, sums them, then adds the VAT and adds it to a grand total, I've managed most of this but I get an error when summing the total & VAT. I've researched NaN meaning not a number, or a sign of error. I've tried but to the best of my knowledge I can't seem to understand why my grand total outputs NaN when adding my VAT and sum, I ran it through a validator and I still couldn't find the error (sorry for this I'm an inexperienced programmer, I'm trying my best)

```
 function sumTotal() {
        let val1 = document.getElementsByName("val1")[0].value;
        let val2 = document.getElementsByName("val2")[0].value;
        let sum = Number(val1) + Number(val2);
        document.getElementsByName("sum")[0].value = sum;
        vatCalc(sum)
        grandTotal(sum)
    }
    function vatCalc (sum) {
        var sumVat =0.20;
         let vat = sumVat*sum;
         document.getElementsByName("vat")[0].value = vat;
}
function grandTotal (sum, vat) {
      let total = Number(sum) + Number(vat);
      document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value= total;

}
```

Thank you so much in advanced for anyone that will help!

Answer (score 4):

`grandTotal()` takes two arguments, but in your `grandTotal(sum)` under `sumTotal()`, you are putting only one argument. Make sure to pass in `vat`

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately nothing is outputted to the grand total field when I try it

Comment: I think you were trying to do either of the following: 1) make vatCalc() calculate vat and call document.getElememntByName in grandTotal() or 2) make vatCalc(sum) return vat and use it to pass in to grandTotal(). In the second case, when you call `vatCalc(sum)`, you need to save off the result in a variable. `let vat = vatCalc(sum)`. Also, in your `vatCalc(sum)`, you need to `return` the result

Comment: function vatCalc (sum) {
        var sumVat =0.20;
         let vat = sumVat*sum;
         return vat;
}

Comment: function sumTotal() {
        let val1 = document.getElementsByName("val1")[0].value;
        let val2 = document.getElementsByName("val2")[0].value;
        let sum = Number(val1) + Number(val2);
        document.getElementsByName("sum")[0].value = sum;
        let vat = vatCalc(sum);
        grandTotal(sum, vat);
    }

Comment: oh I see! I was trying to initialise sum in my grTotal method but I wasn't quite sure how to about it, thank you so much